# Modifying files containing SUB/escape characters

Tags: python, python-2.7, unicode

I am beginning to learn Python and want to use it to automate a process.
The process consists in

1. modifying a few lines of a file
2. use the file as the input for an executable
3. save, move, etc
4. repeat

The problem is that the file I'm trying to modify was written in a language that utilizes the [SUB character](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Substitute_character) to run. Therefore, when I try

```
with open(myFile,'r') as file:
  data = list(file)
```

`data` does not contain any information beyond the SUB character.

Therefore, I need to be able to do two things:

1. Read the whole file in python (without exiting prematurely at the SUB character locations) so that I can modify it.
2. Be able to run it on the executable (that is, the SUB characters need to be back at their respective places).

Any suggestions on how to go about solving this problem?

Thanks

Comment: What code have you tried so far?

Comment: I tried making a list of the opened file with the hopes of making it more easily modifiable.

Comment: `file` is already a list of lines. What content are you expecting in file? You could print it in a for loop. If there are non-printable characters use `"rb"` to open binary files. You also may take care of the encoding of the file. If nothing helps please provide your input file...

Comment: Try using mode `'rb'` when opening the file to specify that you are expecting a binary.  Maybe the ␚ problems derive just from that.  You didn't specify your OS, so maybe yours is "honoring" the ␚ in such a way that it interprets it as an end-of-file marker.

Comment: Thanks @wenzul using 'rb' mode worked and now I can modify and write it back into a file that still runs on my external application.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the [binary mode](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/inputoutput.html#reading-and-writing-files) to open file.

```
with open(myFile,'rb') as file:
    for line in file:
        print line
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you on Windows?  Quoted from your link to the SUB character:

> In CP/M, 86-DOS, MS-DOS, PC DOS, DR-DOS and their various derivatives, character 26 was also used to indicate the end of a character stream, and thereby used to terminate user input in an interactive command line window (and as such, often used to finish console input redirection, e.g. as instigated by COPY CON: TYPEDTXT.TXT).
>
> While no longer technically required to indicate the end of a file many text editors and program languages up to the present still support this convention...

Python 2.7 in text mode will stop at a `CTRL-Z` character (hex 1A), so open the file in binary mode:

Example:

```
# Create a file with embedded character 1Ah
with open('sub.txt','wb') as f:
    f.write(b'abc\x1adef')

# Open in default (text) mode and read as much as possible
with open('sub.txt','r') as f:
    print repr(f.read())

# Open in binary mode
with open('sub.txt','rb') as f:
    print repr(f.read())
```

Output:

```
'abc'
'abc\x1adef'
```